# How to get child window url into parentwindow in react.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an code in reactjs. I'm gonna open another url in my child component

```
 twitterPopup = () => {
    var currentChild = false;
    if (currentChild) child.close();

    child = window.open(
      "http://10.10.1.1:9090/api/v1/twitter/login",
      "",
      "location=0,toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436"
    );
    this.props.twitterEvent(true);
    timer = setInterval(this.checkChild, 500);
    currentChild = true;
  };

  checkChild = () => {
    if (child.closed) {
      alert("window closed");
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  };
```

If I redirect my url (eg `http://localhost:3000?data=234234234432`) 
I checked in my url detected with `data` is came (`window.close()`). 
In my `checkChild` function, got alert field.

Helpme, how to get the data in parent window

Comment: What data are you trying to get? I get the close event when I do it here: https://jsfiddle.net/maniator/5av8740L/

Comment: @NaftaliakaNeal. I got a alert message. How can i get url from child window?

Comment: I am not sure you can

Comment: is there any way to solve it? @NaftaliakaNeal

Comment: Not that I know of. There are also cross origin requests that you have to deal with (cannot read a window that is not from the same origin domain)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get data from a third party child window, without the corporation of the other site due to security restrictions in the browser.

If you own both sites then you can workaround this using either the PostMessage API or CORS.

Comment: No @DavidBradshaw. In my child window, after  authorization. I redirect to my website. In my child window I have same url what i have in parent window. but in child window I have two a query in the url.  I need that query value in to my parent window. thats whats I'm askig

Comment: In that case you need to use the postMessage API to send the data from the child to the parent

Comment: Hey @David Bradshaw. I fixed the issue. I just set the url in my cookie & use it in parent window.